# Is there a way to reduce this CTE with functions or similar? (big query)

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, window-functions

I have a query that I'm running for analyzing data in a table, the table is huge in amount of fields and I need to try to come up with a way to simplify the way it operates.

I have this basic query that returns information about horse races and and provides information about dates and results of the races.

```
SELECT 
td.EVENT_ID, 
       td.MENU_HINT, 
       td.EVENT_NAME,
       td.BSP,
       td.EVENT_DT AS Expr1003, 
       td.WIN_LOSE,
       (SELECT count(*) FROM dbo.tblData td2 WHERE td2.EVENT_ID =td.EVENT_ID) AS [CountRunners],
       SUM(CASE WHEN td.EVENT_ID = td.EVENT_ID THEN 1  END) AS [Total Runners], 
       SUM(CASE WHEN td.WIN_LOSE = 1 THEN td.BSP  END) AS [WinnerPrice],
       SUM(CASE WHEN td.WIN_LOSE = 1 THEN 1 END) AS [WinnerCount],
       td.[Race No] AS RaceNo, 
       replace(LEFT(SUBSTRING(td.EVENT_NAME, CHARINDEX(' ', td.EVENT_NAME) + 1, LEN(td.EVENT_NAME)), CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(td.EVENT_NAME, CHARINDEX(' ', td.EVENT_NAME) + 2, LEN(td.EVENT_NAME)))),'m','') AS Distance, 
       REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(td.EVENT_NAME), CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(td.EVENT_NAME)) - 1)) AS Class, 
       FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, td.EVENT_DT, 103), 'dddd') AS [Day],
       DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CONVERT(DATETIME, td.EVENT_DT, 103)) AS [DayNumber]
FROM tblData td
--WHERE td.EVENT_ID IN(144705336)
GROUP BY td.EVENT_ID, 
         td.MENU_HINT, 
         td.EVENT_NAME, 
         td.BSP,
         td.EVENT_DT, 
         td.[Race No],
         td.WIN_LOSE

╔═══════════╦══════════════════════════╦═══════════════╦════════╦════════════╦══════════╦══════════════╦═══════════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╦════════╦══════════╦═══════╦════════╦═══════════╗
║  EVENT_ID ║ MENU_HINT                ║ EVENT_NAME    ║ BSP    ║ Expr1003   ║ WIN_LOSE ║ CountRunners ║ Total Runners ║ WinnerPrice ║ WinnerCount ║ RaceNo ║ Distance ║ Class ║ Day    ║ DayNumber ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════════╬════════╬════════════╬══════════╬══════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬════════╬══════════╬═══════╬════════╬═══════════╣
║ 138386456 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R1 1000m 2yo  ║ 4.75   ║ 2018-01-01 ║ 1        ║ 7            ║ 1             ║ 4.75        ║ 1           ║ 1      ║ 1000     ║ 2yo   ║ Monday ║ 2         ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════════╬════════╬════════════╬══════════╬══════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬════════╬══════════╬═══════╬════════╬═══════════╣
║ 138386456 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R1 1000m 2yo  ║ 5.01   ║ 2018-01-01 ║ 0        ║ 7            ║ 1             ║ NULL        ║ NULL        ║ 1      ║ 1000     ║ 2yo   ║ Monday ║ 2         ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════════╬════════╬════════════╬══════════╬══════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬════════╬══════════╬═══════╬════════╬═══════════╣
║ 138386456 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R1 1000m 2yo  ║ 5.60   ║ 2018-01-01 ║ 0        ║ 7            ║ 1             ║ NULL        ║ NULL        ║ 1      ║ 1000     ║ 2yo   ║ Monday ║ 2         ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════════╬════════╬════════════╬══════════╬══════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬════════╬══════════╬═══════╬════════╬═══════════╣
║ 138386456 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R1 1000m 2yo  ║ 7.80   ║ 2018-01-01 ║ 0        ║ 7            ║ 1             ║ NULL        ║ NULL        ║ 1      ║ 1000     ║ 2yo   ║ Monday ║ 2         ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════════╬════════╬════════════╬══════════╬══════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬════════╬══════════╬═══════╬════════╬═══════════╣
║ 138386456 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R1 1000m 2yo  ║ 8.70   ║ 2018-01-01 ║ 0        ║ 7            ║ 1             ║ NULL        ║ NULL        ║ 1      ║ 1000     ║ 2yo   ║ Monday ║ 2         ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════════╬════════╬════════════╬══════════╬══════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬════════╬══════════╬═══════╬════════╬═══════════╣
║ 138386456 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R1 1000m 2yo  ║ 8.88   ║ 2018-01-01 ║ 0        ║ 7            ║ 1             ║ NULL        ║ NULL        ║ 1      ║ 1000     ║ 2yo   ║ Monday ║ 2         ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════════╬════════╬════════════╬══════════╬══════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬════════╬══════════╬═══════╬════════╬═══════════╣
║ 138386456 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R1 1000m 2yo  ║ 16.50  ║ 2018-01-01 ║ 0        ║ 7            ║ 1             ║ NULL        ║ NULL        ║ 1      ║ 1000     ║ 2yo   ║ Monday ║ 2         ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════════╬════════╬════════════╬══════════╬══════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬════════╬══════════╬═══════╬════════╬═══════════╣
║ 138386458 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R2 1400m Hcap ║ 3.52   ║ 2018-01-01 ║ 1        ║ 8            ║ 1             ║ 3.52        ║ 1           ║ 2      ║ 1400     ║ Hcap  ║ Monday ║ 2         ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════════╬════════╬════════════╬══════════╬══════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬════════╬══════════╬═══════╬════════╬═══════════╣
║ 138386458 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R2 1400m Hcap ║ 5.00   ║ 2018-01-01 ║ 0        ║ 8            ║ 1             ║ NULL        ║ NULL        ║ 2      ║ 1400     ║ Hcap  ║ Monday ║ 2         ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════════╬════════╬════════════╬══════════╬══════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬════════╬══════════╬═══════╬════════╬═══════════╣
║ 138386458 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R2 1400m Hcap ║ 5.63   ║ 2018-01-01 ║ 0        ║ 8            ║ 1             ║ NULL        ║ NULL        ║ 2      ║ 1400     ║ Hcap  ║ Monday ║ 2         ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════════╬════════╬════════════╬══════════╬══════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬════════╬══════════╬═══════╬════════╬═══════════╣
║ 138386458 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R2 1400m Hcap ║ 5.92   ║ 2018-01-01 ║ 0        ║ 8            ║ 1             ║ NULL        ║ NULL        ║ 2      ║ 1400     ║ Hcap  ║ Monday ║ 2         ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════════╬════════╬════════════╬══════════╬══════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬════════╬══════════╬═══════╬════════╬═══════════╣
║ 138386458 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 1st Jan ║ R2 1400m Hcap ║ 12.52  ║ 2018-01-01 ║ 0        ║ 8            ║ 1             ║ NULL        ║ NULL        ║ 2      ║ 1400     ║ Hcap  ║ Monday ║ 2         ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════════╬════════╬════════════╬══════════╬══════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬════════╬══════════╬═══════╬════════╬═══════════╣
```

Now, for this I have to create a new set of columns to calculate a big set of categories and combinations for different price brackets, amount of runners, distance, race number, etc. I will paste a small subset of the big query that I did with a CTE:

```
 WITH CTE_TblData as(
SELECT 
td.EVENT_ID, 
       td.MENU_HINT, 
       td.EVENT_NAME,
       td.BSP,
       td.EVENT_DT AS Expr1003, 
       td.WIN_LOSE,
       (SELECT count(*) FROM dbo.tblData td2 WHERE td2.EVENT_ID =td.EVENT_ID) AS [CountRunners],
       SUM(CASE WHEN td.EVENT_ID = td.EVENT_ID THEN 1  END) AS [Total Runners], 
       SUM(CASE WHEN td.WIN_LOSE = 1 THEN td.BSP  END) AS [WinnerPrice],
       SUM(CASE WHEN td.WIN_LOSE = 1 THEN 1 END) AS [WinnerCount],
       td.[Race No] AS RaceNo, 
       replace(LEFT(SUBSTRING(td.EVENT_NAME, CHARINDEX(' ', td.EVENT_NAME) + 1, LEN(td.EVENT_NAME)), CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(td.EVENT_NAME, CHARINDEX(' ', td.EVENT_NAME) + 2, LEN(td.EVENT_NAME)))),'m','') AS Distance, 
       REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(td.EVENT_NAME), CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(td.EVENT_NAME)) - 1)) AS Class, 
       FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, td.EVENT_DT, 103), 'dddd') AS [Day],
       DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CONVERT(DATETIME, td.EVENT_DT, 103)) AS [DayNumber]
FROM tblData td
--WHERE td.EVENT_ID IN(144705336)
GROUP BY td.EVENT_ID, 
         td.MENU_HINT, 
         td.EVENT_NAME, 
         td.BSP,
         td.EVENT_DT, 
         td.[Race No],
         td.WIN_LOSE
         )



    SELECT 
    td.event_id,

    count(CASE WHEN td.BSP >1 AND td.BSP <=2 AND td.WIN_LOSE = 1 THEN td.BSP END) AS CountWinnerPrice1to2,
    sum(CASE WHEN td.BSP >1 AND td.BSP <=2 AND td.WIN_LOSE = 1 THEN td.BSP END) AS SumWinnerPrice1to2,
    count(CASE WHEN td.BSP >1 AND td.BSP <=2 AND td.WIN_LOSE = 1 AND td.CountRunners >0 AND td.CountRunners <=7 THEN td.BSP END) AS CountWinnerPrice1to2Runners0to7,
    sum(CASE WHEN td.BSP >1 AND td.BSP <=2 AND td.WIN_LOSE = 1 AND td.CountRunners >0 AND td.CountRunners <=7 THEN td.BSP END) AS SumWinnerPrice1to2Runners0to7,
    count(CASE WHEN td.BSP >1 AND td.BSP <=2 AND td.WIN_LOSE = 1 AND td.Distance >0 AND td.Distance <=1200 THEN td.BSP END) AS CountWinnerPrice1to2Distance0to1200,
    sum(CASE WHEN td.BSP >1 AND td.BSP <=2 AND td.WIN_LOSE = 1 AND td.Distance >0 AND td.Distance <=1200 THEN td.BSP END) AS SumWinnerPrice1to2Distance0to1200,
    sum(CASE WHEN td.BSP >2 AND td.BSP <=3 AND td.WIN_LOSE = 1 AND td.RaceNo >0 AND td.RaceNo <=4 THEN td.BSP END) AS SumWinnerPrice2to3raceno0to4,
    count(CASE WHEN td.BSP >2 AND td.BSP <=3 AND td.WIN_LOSE = 0 AND td.RaceNo >0 AND td.RaceNo <=4 THEN td.BSP END) AS CountWinnerNotPrice2to3raceno0to4,
    count(CASE WHEN td.BSP >1 AND td.BSP <=2 AND td.WIN_LOSE = 0 AND td.Class in ('CL1','CL2','CL3') THEN td.BSP END) AS CountWinnerNotPrice1to2DayCL1orCL2orCL3,
    sum(CASE WHEN td.BSP >1 AND td.BSP <=2 AND td.WIN_LOSE = 0 AND td.Class in ('CL1','CL2','CL3') THEN td.BSP END) AS SumWinnerNotPrice1to2DayCL1orCL2orCL3,
    count(CASE WHEN td.BSP >1 AND td.BSP <=2 AND td.WIN_LOSE = 0 AND td.DayNumber in (5,6) THEN td.BSP END) AS CountWinnerNotPrice1to2Day5or6,
    sum(CASE WHEN td.BSP >1 AND td.BSP <=2 AND td.WIN_LOSE = 0 AND td.DayNumber in (5,6) THEN td.BSP END) AS SumWinnerNotPrice1to2Day5or6,
    isnull((SELECT count(td2.BSP - CASE WHEN td2.WIN_LOSE =1 THEN 1 end)  FROM dbo.tblData td2 WHERE td2.EVENT_ID = td.EVENT_ID AND td2.BSP >2 AND td2.BSP <3 HAVING count(td2.BSP) IN(0,1)   ),0) AS CountWinnerPrice2to3Runners0to1,
    (SELECT sum(td2.BSP - CASE WHEN td2.WIN_LOSE =0 THEN td2.BSP ELSE 0 end)  FROM dbo.tblData td2 WHERE td2.EVENT_ID = td.EVENT_ID AND td2.BSP >2 AND td2.BSP <3 HAVING count(td2.BSP) IN(0,1)   ) AS SumWinnerPrice2to3Runners0to1,
    isnull((SELECT count(td2.BSP - CASE WHEN td2.WIN_LOSE =0 THEN 1 end)  FROM dbo.tblData td2 WHERE td2.EVENT_ID = td.EVENT_ID AND td2.BSP >2 AND td2.BSP <3 HAVING count(td2.BSP) IN(0,1)   ),0) AS CountWinnerNotPrice2to3Runners0to1,
    (SELECT sum(td2.BSP - CASE WHEN td2.WIN_LOSE =1 THEN td2.BSP ELSE 0 end)  FROM dbo.tblData td2 WHERE td2.EVENT_ID = td.EVENT_ID AND td2.BSP >2 AND td2.BSP <3 HAVING count(td2.BSP) IN(0,1)   ) AS SumWinnerNotPrice2to3Runners0to1
FROM CTE_TblData td
WHERE td.class not in ('S', 'M', 'Trot', 'Pace')
GROUP BY td.event_id, td.MENU_HINT, td.EVENT_NAME, td.Expr1003, td.RaceNo, td.Distance, td.Class, td.[Day]
Order by td.Expr1003 desc, td.raceno desc, event_id desc
```

this is just to give a small Idea of what I'm dealing with, the query returns 900 different fields for the combinations I need.

here is a paste of the table result:

```
╔═══════════╦══════════════════════╦════════════════════╦═════════════════════════════════╦═══════════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════════════════╦═══════════════════════════════════╦══════════════════════════════╦═══════════════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════════════════════╦═══════════════════════════════════════╦════════════════════════════════╦══════════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════════════╦═══════════════════════════════╦════════════════════════════════════╦══════════════════════════════════╗
║  event_id ║ CountWinnerPrice1to2 ║ SumWinnerPrice1to2 ║ CountWinnerPrice1to2Runners0to7 ║ SumWinnerPrice1to2Runners0to7 ║ CountWinnerPrice1to2Distance0to1200 ║ SumWinnerPrice1to2Distance0to1200 ║ SumWinnerPrice2to3raceno0to4 ║ CountWinnerNotPrice2to3raceno0to4 ║ CountWinnerNotPrice1to2DayCL1orCL2orCL3 ║ SumWinnerNotPrice1to2DayCL1orCL2orCL3 ║ CountWinnerNotPrice1to2Day5or6 ║ SumWinnerNotPrice1to2Day5or6 ║ CountWinnerPrice2to3Runners0to1 ║ SumWinnerPrice2to3Runners0to1 ║ CountWinnerNotPrice2to3Runners0to1 ║ SumWinnerNotPrice2to3Runners0to1 ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════╬════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════╣
║ 146356540 ║ 1                    ║ 1.54               ║ 1                               ║ 1.54                          ║ 0                                   ║ NULL                              ║ NULL                         ║ 0                                 ║ 0                                       ║ NULL                                  ║ 0                              ║ NULL                         ║ 0                               ║ NULL                          ║ 0                                  ║ NULL                             ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════╬════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════╣
║ 146325088 ║ 0                    ║ NULL               ║ 0                               ║ NULL                          ║ 0                                   ║ NULL                              ║ NULL                         ║ 0                                 ║ 0                                       ║ NULL                                  ║ 0                              ║ NULL                         ║ 0                               ║ 0.00                          ║ 1                                  ║ 2.19                             ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════════════╬════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════╣
║ 146325086 ║ 0                    ║ NULL               ║ 0                               ║ NULL                          ║ 0                                   ║ NULL                              ║ NULL                         ║ 0                                 ║ 0                                       ║ NULL                                  ║ 0                              ║ NULL                         ║ 0                               ║ NULL                          ║ 0                                  ║ NULL                             ║
```

now, if this isn't long enough, I need to calculate profit and losses for each column bracket now. for this I'm using a combination of CTE within CTE to order the groups. I'm attaching a small screenshot that explains what needs to be done and then the calculations I do for this:

[image]

and a subset of the query that I'm running for it with the fields from the screenshot:

```
WITH base 
     AS (SELECT td.EVENT_ID AS event_id, 
                td.MENU_HINT AS race, 
                td.EVENT_NAME AS event, 
                td.expr1003 AS [date], 
                td.raceno AS [race number], 
                td.countwinnerprice5to8, -- AS [count1],
                td.sumwinnerprice5to8, -- AS [sum1],
                td.countwinnernotprice5to8, -- AS [count2],
                td.sumwinnernotprice5to8, -- AS [sum2],
                td.countwinnerprice8to13, -- AS [count1],
                td.sumwinnerprice8to13, -- AS [sum1],
                td.countwinnernotprice8to13, -- AS [count2],
                td.sumwinnernotprice8to13, -- AS [sum2],
                LEAD(td.sumwinnerprice5to8, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY countwinnerprice5to8
                ORDER BY expr1003 DESC, 
                         raceno DESC, 
                         event_id DESC) AS lead_sumwinnerprice5to8, 
                LEAD(td.sumwinnerprice8to13, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY countwinnerprice8to13
                ORDER BY expr1003 DESC, 
                         raceno DESC, 
                         event_id DESC) AS lead_sumwinnerprice8to13
         FROM tbldata5 td
         WHERE menu_hint LIKE '%Flem%'),
     base_grouped
       -- First, create a group identifier, but in the -opposite- direction
  -- (This will group the rows where you want to sum [count2])
     AS (SELECT base.event_id, 
                base.race, 
                base.event, 
                base.[date], 
                base.[race number], 
                base.countwinnerprice5to8, 
                base.sumwinnerprice5to8, 
                base.countwinnernotprice5to8, 
                base.sumwinnernotprice5to8, 
                base.countwinnerprice8to13, 
                base.sumwinnerprice8to13, 
                base.countwinnernotprice8to13, 
                base.sumwinnernotprice8to13, 
                base.lead_sumwinnerprice5to8, 
                base.lead_sumwinnerprice8to13, 
                SUM(countwinnerprice5to8) OVER(
                ORDER BY [date], 
                         [race number], 
                         event_id) AS group_id, 
                SUM(countwinnerprice8to13) OVER(
                ORDER BY [date], 
                         [race number], 
                         event_id) AS group_id2
         FROM base),
     base_grouped_summed
       -- Then do the sum on [count2] within those groups
     AS (SELECT base_grouped.event_id, 
                base_grouped.race, 
                base_grouped.event, 
                base_grouped.[date], 
                base_grouped.[race number], 
                base_grouped.countwinnerprice5to8, 
                base_grouped.sumwinnerprice5to8, 
                base_grouped.countwinnernotprice5to8, 
                base_grouped.sumwinnernotprice5to8, 
                base_grouped.countwinnerprice8to13, 
                base_grouped.sumwinnerprice8to13, 
                base_grouped.countwinnernotprice8to13, 
                base_grouped.sumwinnernotprice8to13, 
                base_grouped.lead_sumwinnerprice5to8, 
                base_grouped.lead_sumwinnerprice8to13, 
                base_grouped.group_id, 
                base_grouped.group_id2, 
                SUM(countwinnernotprice5to8) OVER(PARTITION BY group_id) AS sum_count2, 
                SUM(countwinnernotprice8to13) OVER(PARTITION BY group_id) AS sum_count3
         FROM base_grouped)
         -- Now deduct it from [lead2] (only does anything when [lead2] is not null)
     SELECT base_grouped_summed.event_id, 
            base_grouped_summed.race, 
            base_grouped_summed.event, 
            base_grouped_summed.[date], 
            base_grouped_summed.[race number], 
            base_grouped_summed.countwinnerprice5to8, 
            base_grouped_summed.sumwinnerprice5to8, 
            base_grouped_summed.countwinnernotprice5to8, 
            base_grouped_summed.sumwinnernotprice5to8,
            base_grouped_summed.group_id, 
            base_grouped_summed.sum_count2,
            (lead_sumwinnerprice5to8 - LAG(sum_count2) OVER(
             ORDER BY group_id)) - 1 AS [Profit_Loss], 
            base_grouped_summed.countwinnerprice8to13, 
            base_grouped_summed.sumwinnerprice8to13, 
            base_grouped_summed.countwinnernotprice8to13, 
            base_grouped_summed.sumwinnernotprice8to13, 
            base_grouped_summed.lead_sumwinnerprice5to8, 
            base_grouped_summed.lead_sumwinnerprice8to13, 
            base_grouped_summed.group_id2,  
            base_grouped_summed.sum_count3, 
            (lead_sumwinnerprice8to13 - LAG(sum_count3) OVER(
             ORDER BY group_id)) - 1 AS [Profit_Loss2]
     FROM base_grouped_summed
     ORDER BY [date] DESC, 
              [race number] DESC, 
              event_id DESC;
```

and a slice of the table it outputs:

```
╔═══════════╦═══════════════════════════╦═══════════════╦════════════╦═════════════╦══════════════════════╦════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╦═══════════════════════╦══════════╦════════════╦═════════════╦═══════════════════════╦═════════════════════╦══════════════════════════╦════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╦══════════════════════════╦═══════════╦════════════╦══════════════╗
║  event_id ║ race                      ║ event         ║ date       ║ race number ║ countwinnerprice5to8 ║ sumwinnerprice5to8 ║ countwinnernotprice5to8 ║ sumwinnernotprice5to8 ║ group_id ║ sum_count2 ║ Profit_Loss ║ countwinnerprice8to13 ║ sumwinnerprice8to13 ║ countwinnernotprice8to13 ║ sumwinnernotprice8to13 ║ lead_sumwinnerprice5to8 ║ lead_sumwinnerprice8to13 ║ group_id2 ║ sum_count3 ║ Profit_Loss2 ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═══════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════════════════╬════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬══════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═══════════════════════╬═════════════════════╬══════════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════╬════════════╬══════════════╣
║ 145719665 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 21st Jul ║ R9 1000m Hcap ║ 2018-07-21 ║ 9           ║ 0                    ║ NULL               ║ 1                       ║ 7.40                  ║ 25       ║ 6          ║ NULL        ║ 0                     ║ NULL                ║ 1                        ║ 10.08                  ║ NULL                    ║ NULL                     ║ 24        ║ 13         ║ NULL         ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═══════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════════════════╬════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬══════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═══════════════════════╬═════════════════════╬══════════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════╬════════════╬══════════════╣
║ 145719663 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 21st Jul ║ R8 2000m Hcap ║ 2018-07-21 ║ 8           ║ 0                    ║ NULL               ║ 0                       ║ NULL                  ║ 25       ║ 6          ║ NULL        ║ 0                     ║ NULL                ║ 2                        ║ 20.94                  ║ NULL                    ║ NULL                     ║ 24        ║ 13         ║ NULL         ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═══════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════════════════╬════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬══════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═══════════════════════╬═════════════════════╬══════════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════╬════════════╬══════════════╣
║ 145719661 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 21st Jul ║ R7 1600m 3yo  ║ 2018-07-21 ║ 7           ║ 0                    ║ NULL               ║ 1                       ║ 6.22                  ║ 25       ║ 6          ║ NULL        ║ 1                     ║ 12.50               ║ 0                        ║ NULL                   ║ NULL                    ║ 11.83                    ║ 24        ║ 13         ║ -2.17        ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═══════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════════════════╬════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬══════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═══════════════════════╬═════════════════════╬══════════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════╬════════════╬══════════════╣
║ 145719659 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 21st Jul ║ R6 1100m 3yo  ║ 2018-07-21 ║ 6           ║ 0                    ║ NULL               ║ 1                       ║ 7.60                  ║ 25       ║ 6          ║ NULL        ║ 0                     ║ NULL                ║ 1                        ║ 12.95                  ║ NULL                    ║ NULL                     ║ 23        ║ 13         ║ NULL         ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═══════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════════════════╬════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬══════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═══════════════════════╬═════════════════════╬══════════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════╬════════════╬══════════════╣
║ 145719657 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 21st Jul ║ R5 1800m 2yo  ║ 2018-07-21 ║ 5           ║ 0                    ║ NULL               ║ 1                       ║ 7.69                  ║ 25       ║ 6          ║ NULL        ║ 0                     ║ NULL                ║ 0                        ║ NULL                   ║ NULL                    ║ NULL                     ║ 23        ║ 13         ║ NULL         ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═══════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════════════════╬════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬══════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═══════════════════════╬═════════════════════╬══════════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════╬════════════╬══════════════╣
║ 145719655 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 21st Jul ║ R4 1200m Hcap ║ 2018-07-21 ║ 4           ║ 0                    ║ NULL               ║ 1                       ║ 5.90                  ║ 25       ║ 6          ║ NULL        ║ 1                     ║ 11.83               ║ 2                        ║ 23.83                  ║ NULL                    ║ 9.96                     ║ 23        ║ 13         ║ -4.04        ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═══════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════════════════╬════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬══════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═══════════════════════╬═════════════════════╬══════════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬══════════════════════════╬═══════════╬════════════╬══════════════╣
║ 145719653 ║ AUS / Flem (AUS) 21st Jul ║ R3 2500m Hcap ║ 2018-07-21 ║ 3           ║ 0                    ║ NULL               ║ 0                       ║ NULL                  ║ 25       ║ 6          ║ NULL        ║ 0                     ║ NULL                ║ 3                        ║ 35.02                  ║ NULL                    ║ NULL                     ║ 22        ║ 13         ║ NULL         ║
╚═══════════╩═══════════════════════════╩═══════════════╩════════════╩═════════════╩══════════════════════╩════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╩═══════════════════════╩══════════╩════════════╩═════════════╩═══════════════════════╩═════════════════════╩══════════════════════════╩════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╩══════════════════════════╩═══════════╩════════════╩══════════════╝
```

So, what I'm trying to do now is to find a way to reduce all this calculations now.

I'm aware that the current method is awful and could be improved.
the data that is operated doesn't change historically so this could be saved on tables and operated with to reduce coding logic. but I was trying to somehow reduce the overall code for the "profit/loss" part as this will require a lot of code to generate each column and then call it in the proper place. Is there a way that the last query could be reduced with functions for example?

I can provide DDL of the main table and some data if it helps.